# controlling links on right mouse clicks in my website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching for examples of custom on mouse right click menus but i would like to emulate the same options you get when you right click in chrome on a web page Maintaining cut, copy, and paste but also (here is the tricky part) instead of opening a new tab in your browser it opens the same webpage inside an iframe, option.

Thanks

Comment: Not a bad question, but why -- some limited usage UI? Because, it will be not a very pretty thing in the eyes of browser compatibility.

Comment: You're going to run into some interesting problems accessing dynamically-generated IFRAMES cross-browser. There are timing issues on top of some oddness surrounding how to identify an IFRAME. Just FYI.

Comment: Note that not all browsers support Javascript on right mouse click, for example Opera.

Comment: That sounds evil. Are you *really* sure you want to do that?

Comment: not trying to fool users @missingno (funny coming from someone whos  name is a bug that game developers created that would corrupt your game save) its for a social experiment to study behavior.

Comment: it dosent have to be an iframe but i want to be able to open the page inside my page. Thanks guys for your comments.

Comment: I don't corrupt saves, I give people more masterballs :P Are you sure you can't write a browser extension or something like that instead? Any Javascript solution is going to be a big hack and it sounds like you have control over the environment anyway...

Comment: What i want is to be able to open a new link in a new tab by right clicking using this [link](http://jsbin.com/uruto4/) Thanks guys for your comments hope this helps understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin, it might help you

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryContextMenu

Comment: Thanks it does help, but i still need help on being able to open a new browser window inside my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest hiding the "Window" which will be a div or some HTML element
Once user has right clicked on an element you can access it through jquery selectors and
enable it's visibility.

```
css:

#hiddenFrame {

display: none;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;

}


javascript:


menu1 = { attributes: "brief_number,brief_id,...",
  items:  [
                {
                 type:RightContext.TYPE_MENU,
                 text:"some text",
                 onclick:function() {$('#hiddenFrame').show();}
                }
          ]
        };
```